# Egulias Email validator error when upgrading from Drupal 9.5 to 10.1.8 using composer

Tags: composer, 10, upgrading

I am trying to upgrade from Drupal 9.5 to 10.1.8 using composer. I have used upgrade status module to ensure that all modules are compatible with Drupal 10.

I have used the composer command to begin the upgrade.

```
composer require drupal/core-recommended:10.1.8 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:10.1.8 drupal/core-project-message:10.1.8 --update-with-all-dependencies
```

However I keep running into the following error.

```
  - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended 10.1.8 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.1.8].
- drupal/core-recommended 10.1.8 requires egulias/email-validator ~4.0.1 -> found egulias/email-validator[4.0.1, 4.0.2] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require
```

Trying to debug the error results in

```
 composer why-not egulias/email-validator 4.0.1
drupal/core             9.5.11      requires         egulias/email-validator (^2.1.22|^3.2)  
drupal/core-recommended 9.5.11      requires         egulias/email-validator (~3.2.1)        
swiftmailer/swiftmailer v6.3.0      requires         egulias/email-validator (^2.0|^3.1)     
egulias/email-validator 4.0.1       requires         doctrine/lexer (^2.0 || ^3.0)           
cti/lfhw                dev-develop does not require doctrine/lexer (but 1.2.3 is installed) 
Not finding what you were looking for? Try calling `composer update "egulias/email-validator:
```

I am not able to understand what should be done to resolve the issue and what is locking the validator to this specific version.

Answer (score 1):

Swift Mailer module has been deprecated, see [Swift Mailer - Moderately critical - Access bypass - SA-CONTRIB-2024-006](https://www.drupal.org/sa-contrib-2024-006), so you should consider switching to [Drupal Symfony Mailer](https://www.drupal.org/project/symfony_mailer) which will probably fix this dependency.